# $(document).ready() - How it is being executed?

Tags: jquery

`$(document).ready()` - How it is being executed?. Whether the cursor will be waiting in that piece of line in order to execute the code after DOM creation OR this method will be executed like event handler after the DOM has been created by the browser?

What if the image doesnt get downloaded but the `$(document).ready()` gets executed to read the that image's `src` attribute to assign to some other local variable after the DOM construction?

Comment: The image's `src` will exist in the DOM regardless of the image resource being available to be embedded/visible in the page. But +1 for asking a question I hadn't thought about until now. =)

Comment: In addition to this, `$(window).load()` gets executed after all resources load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an event handler, and it *doesn't* wait for everything to download. It only waits until the DOM has been constructed and is `ready` to be transformed. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.

Code behind it is fairly simple, actually. It just waits for `document.body` to be accessible (not null):

```
function (wait) {
    // Either a released hold or an DOMready/load event and not yet ready
    if ((wait === true && !--jQuery.readyWait) || (wait !== true && !jQuery.isReady)) {
        // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
        if (!document.body) {
            return setTimeout(jQuery.ready, 1);
        }

        // Remember that the DOM is ready
        jQuery.isReady = true;

        // If a normal DOM Ready event fired, decrement, and wait if need be
        if (wait !== true && --jQuery.readyWait > 0) {
            return;
        }

        // If there are functions bound, to execute
        readyList.resolveWith(document, [jQuery]);

        // Trigger any bound ready events
        if (jQuery.fn.trigger) {
            jQuery(document).trigger("ready").unbind("ready");
        }
    }
}
```

From http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.ready

Answer (score 1):

The .ready() code block is parsed/prepped at the time it's encountered within the page, but actual execution is deferred until the "ready" condition has been met. You can have as many .ready() blocks as you want - they won't hang the page - they're designed NOT to hang the page.

Comment: If i can add as many .ready() method as i want, will that be executed in the order it present in the page?

Comment: I believe so, but actually not sure about it. I've rarely had to use multiple ready blocks, and none of them were ordering dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It's fired when the DOM is ready.  [Fire when DOM is ready...](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)